# Is this sentence correct "This is her real raw face without making-up"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Is "real raw face" a common term in everyday English conversation, or is there another phrase that can express a similar meaning?

Comment: You might have better luck asking this at [our sister site, English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). Oh, and by the way, I think you mean "without makeup."

Comment: "raw face" sounds queer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the opposite of "raw" is usually "cooked", it's not the best choice of words. Try "natural" or "naked".

"Raw skin" describes skin where the epidermis is missing due to abrasion or other injury.(US)

Comment: seem more people use "naked face" than "natural face" right? there are 10K search result with ""naked face" while  there is only 3k search result with ""natural face"

Answer (score 4):

No. It would not be common to use *raw face* for this kind of meaning, and it would be considered unclear or strange by most English speakers.

*This is her real face, without makeup*

would be more conventional and clear.